# How can i change the pointer of my cursor in winui3?

Tags: winui-3

I want to change my cursor ideally making it invisible but would settle for cross when it enters/exits a specified area.

After some research, I saw Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor always returns null for desktop which is what I use and so it just doesn't work. I've seen you can use reflection but I couldn't find any examples I could get to work, unfortunately. I was hoping someone could help me out.

```
    private void Canvas_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      
       
        
    }
   
    private void Canvas_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      
        
        
     
    }
```

Comment: You have to subclass the Page element: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#core-unsupported-classes *"Instead of the PointerCursor property, use the UIElement.ProtectedCursor property provided by WinUI 3. You'll need to have a subclass of UIElement to access that property"* There are hacky solutions like doing reflection with C# https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/1816 (`InvokeMember("ProtectedCursor", ...`)

Comment: yea i saw that but am struggling to implement it

Comment: I managed to fix it thanks

Comment: @JPWilson Would you like to answer yourself?

Answer (score 1):

For the people who want the answer:

Since we need to access the `ProtectedCursor` property, which is a `protected` property in `Grid`, we need to create a custom `Grid`.

```cs
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    public InputCursor InputCursor
    {
        get => ProtectedCursor;
        set => ProtectedCursor = value;
    }
}
```

Use the `CustomGrid` as the area you want to change the mouse cursor. You need to set the `Background` to make this work.

```xml
<local:CustomGrid
    x:Name="CustomGrid"
    Background="Transparent"
    PointerEntered="CustomGrid_PointerEntered"
    PointerExited="CustomGrid_PointerExited">
    <!--  your contents here.  -->
</local:CustomGrid>
```

then in code-behind:

```cs
private InputCursor? OriginalInputCursor { get; set; }

private void CustomControl_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OriginalInputCursor = this.CustomGrid.InputCursor ?? InputSystemCursor.Create(InputSystemCursorShape.Arrow);
    this.CustomGrid.InputCursor = InputSystemCursor.Create(InputSystemCursorShape.UniversalNo);
}

private void CustomGrid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OriginalInputCursor != null)
    {
        this.CustomGrid.InputCursor = OriginalInputCursor;
    }
}
```